# pasar los datos de un PivotGridControl a un DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, datagridview

Trabajo en vb.net

Requiero pasar los datos de un PivotGridControl(DevExpress v15.2) a un DataGridView ya que requiero enviar el DataGridView  a un metodo que lo recibe como parametro

Intento con el siguiente codigo, sin embargo, el DataGridView no recibe datos.

```
        Dim grid As New DataGridView
        grid.DataSource = PivotGridControl1.DataSource
        ExcelExportLista(grid)
```

Comment: Si pones un punto de interrupción en `ExcelExportLista(grid)`, que valor tiene el datasource del grid? está vacío?

Comment: También puedes probar algo así: 
`PivotGridControl1.ForceInitialize();`
`grid.DataSource = PivotGridControl1.CreateSummaryDataSource();`
`grid.ForceInitialize();`